# head -n $LINES works in terminal but now with script

Tags: linux, bash

So I am trying to limit output of something to height of a terminal, for example:

```
ps -eo user,pid,ppid,comm --sort start_time | head -n "$LINES"
```

Now this works if I write it in a terminal. But for some reason I get an error if I try to run it from a script I either get an error **invalid number of lines** if I use **"$LINES"** or **option requires argument n** if i use only **$LINES**.

So I guess my question is, is there a way to get $LINES or something similar in working in script.

Thank you for your help.

edit: $LINES doesnt save anything when I use it in a script

Answer (score 1):

first line of script write:

```
LINES=$(tput lines)
```

and voila.

Comment: Or just replace `...|head -n "$LINES"` with `...|head -n $(tput lines)`